# Javascript method isn't returning value

Tags: javascript, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to return AJAX response Text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225667/how-to-return-ajax-response-text)
>   [Variable doesn’t get returned JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475269/variable-doesnt-get-returned-jquery)
>   [AJAX not updating variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883813/ajax-not-updating-variable)

I am having issue with this code:

```
/**
 * facebook Object*/
var fbObject = new Object();


/**
 * Function to get login status
 * @returns boolean Logged in status
 * */
fbObject.getLoginStatus = function() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status == 'connected') {
              console.log('logged in');
              return true;
            } else {
              console.log('not logged in');
              return false;
            }
    });
}

var status = fbObject.getLoginStatus();

    alert('Status: '+ status);
```

My problem is that getLoginStatus method isn't returning the value.

Comment: Its ***asynchronous***! And you don't `return` anything from the function, so what would you expect?

Comment: What is the value you are getting for the `response.status`??

Comment: The reason is simple : when getLoginStatus ends, the distant server hasn't received the question nor answered. So you **can't** get something returned.

Comment: @algorhythm Those are probably two distinct functions : one from an API and one from OP.

Comment: Thank you guys found solution here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475269/variable-doesnt-get-returned-from-ajax-function

Answer (score 0):

You need a **callback**

Ajax requests do not return anything, they are ***asynchronous***.

---

Try this:

```
var status = function(s){
    alert('Status: '+ s);
};

/**
 * Function to get login status
 * @returns boolean Logged in status
 * */
fbObject.getLoginStatus = function() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status == 'connected') {
           console.log('logged in');
           status(true);
         } else {
           console.log('not logged in');
           status(false);
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: Tried this but this is also not working :(

Answer (score 0):

The method is asynchronous, you are using it in a synchronous manner. It is impossible to return a value in the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

The function is Asynchronous,

What I would do is to run the "callback code" in the actual callback:

```
    fbObject.getLoginStatus = function() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status == 'connected') {
              console.log('logged in');
              alert('Status: '+ true);
            } else {
              console.log('not logged in');
              alert('Status: '+ false);
            }
    });
}
```

or pass a callback to the function, or stall, until the function has returned.