# Problem fetching value in Array - XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make multiple requests on the server within a `loop for`. I found some tips here and implemented the suggested solution. However, it does not seem to work.

```
var valuePlan = [];
function getValue(id) {
   var f = (function(){
      var xhr = [], i;
      for(i = 0; i < id.length; i++){ //for loop
         (function(i){
            xhr[i] = new XMLHttpRequest();
            url = "get.php?id=" + id[i] + "&for=monthly";
            xhr[i].open("GET", url, true);
            xhr[i].onreadystatechange = function(){
               if (xhr[i].readyState === 4 && xhr[i].status === 200){
                  console.log('Response from request ' + i + ' [ ' + xhr[i].responseText + ']');
                  valuePlan.push(xhr[i].responseText.replace(".", ","));
               }
            };
            xhr[i].send();
         })(i);
      }
   })();
};
getValue([48,52,50]);
console.log(valuePlan[0]);
```

The problem that when I use `console.log(valuePlan[0]);` in console it returns `undefined`, and if it uses `console.log(valuePlan);` returns the `arrays` with the correct values. Can you understand that?

The variable is already defined as global, and even then I can not fetch the individual values of it.

Comment: you may take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883813/ajax-not-updating-variable) or...

Comment: So you have issues with how you are using `i` where when the callback executes, the value of `i` is wrong. And the other issue is you try to order a pizza and eat it before it gets delivered.  The loop finishes before the Ajax calls are done so you log before it is complete.

Comment: you code is `asynchronous` so `valuePlan` will not hold the result values immediadly but at the ends of the ajax calls, you should definitly use `Promise` to handle this type of scenario